# Can we have plugin level filters.yml for Symfony plugins?

Tags: filter, symfony-1.4, symfony-plugins

I'm developing a Symfony plugin to restrict users from accessing a another plugin's action. I thought of implementing this as a symfony filter.

Can I add customize filters by having a plugin level `filters.yml` without having a one main `filters.yml`. This plugin level requirement came because I want to stop users from editing the main filters.yml and using the system.

**PS:** This plugin I'm creating is encrypted and I don't want to encrypt the main application.

Comment: Well yes, but I think you must a default one in your app config dir. But have you tried first?